# Caliburn micro ShowDialog wont appear a second time

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, caliburn.micro, showdialog

I am working on an application that has a splash screen and then a login screen before it pulls up the application. I am using Caliburn Micro to tie everything together but for some reason I am only able to get the Splash Screen to appear. Once the splash screen finishes loading, I call the `secondWindow.ShowDialog(LogOnVM)` and nothing happens. If I comment out the splash screen code, the the login screen does appear just fine. They just don't appear one after another.

I used `Application.Windows.Count` after the second `ShowDialog` gets called and it does show a count of `1`. (It is `0` after the first dialog closes) So I know there is a form opening somewhere but I its not visible or something.
I have even tried creating a new instance of `WindowManager` but that did nothing either.

I have placed:

```
var cmWindowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();            
var cmSplashScreenViewModel = IoC.Get<SplashScreenViewModel>();
cmWindowManager.ShowDialog(cmSplashScreenViewModel);
var cmLogOnViewModel = IoC.Get<LogOnViewModel>();
var result = cmWindowManager.ShowDialog(cmLogOnViewModel);
```

Here is how it is being setup. Should I create a second SimpleContainer

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    LogManager.GetLog = x => new DebugLog(x);
    sc = new SimpleContainer();
    sc.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
    sc.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

    sc.Singleton<IFakeStartupTask, FakeStartupTask>();
    sc.PerRequest<SplashScreenViewModel>();

    sc.Singleton<IMessageBoxService, MessageBoxService>();
    sc.PerRequest<LogOnViewModel>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call TryClose() in your cmSplashScreenViewModel

Below code can show twice the login window (after the 1st login closed)

```
 var login = this.container.GetExportedValue<LoginViewModel>();
 var windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
 windowManager.ShowDialog(login);
 windowManager.ShowDialog(login);
```